# Creating Floating Components in React Native That Persistently Appear Outside the App's Window

Tags: react-native, cross-platform, floating-action-button, mobile-development, native-methods

I need your help, how can I achieve this same thing with react native? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVVLxs7aRPU

I am working with React Native and need to create floating components that can persistently appear and interact outside the app's window. However, I've come to understand that React Native doesn't provide built-in support for such functionality.

According to the React Native documentation, it seems that developing a native module or exploring platform-specific solutions might be necessary to achieve this functionality. However, I would like to confirm if there are any alternative approaches or tools that can help me create floating components or overlays on top of the operating system.

Here is the relevant information I found in my research:

"That's correct. React Native, as a framework, is primarily designed to build mobile applications within the app container provided by the operating system. It does not provide built-in support for creating floating components that can persistently appear and interact outside the app's window.

Floating components that exist outside the app's window and have interactions with elements outside the app typically require platform-specific code and access to lower-level APIs provided by the operating system. This goes beyond the capabilities of React Native alone.

If you have a specific requirement for a floating component that can appear and interact outside the app's window, you may need to consider developing a native module or exploring platform-specific solutions for the particular operating system you are targeting.

Alternatively, you can consider using cross-platform frameworks or tools that provide more extensive support for floating components and interactions outside the app's window. These frameworks or tools may offer features or plugins specifically designed for creating floating components or overlays on top of the operating system."

Comment: Posting a Youtube link without providing summary of code it describes is not a good way to asking a question on StackOverflow. Please embed your expected result as a piece of code or an image of expected layout (or both).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **react-native-draggable** library, You can add floating component.

For more information, You can check this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable

Here is an example of Draggable component

```
import Draggable from 'react-native-draggable';

     <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', flex: 1}} >
        <Draggable 
            imageSource={require('./image.png')} 
            renderSize={80} 
            x={200}
            y={300}
            onDragRelease={this._changeFace}
            onLongPress={()=>console.log('long press')}
            onShortPressRelease={()=>console.log('press drag')}
            onPressIn={()=>console.log('in press')}
            onPressOut={()=>console.log('out press')}
        />  
    </View>
```

Comment: You don't understand, I want the Draggable component to appear outside the App's Window
Here is a link to want I want to achieve https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVVLxs7aRPU